# How can I solve the vector calculation error 'R is of zero length'?

Tags: arrays, r, if-statement, vector

I'm trying to perform a rolling calculation on a vector. I haven't been able to use the the `ifelse` function from the `zoo` package to make the code nice and neat, and I've struggled to find how the `reduce` function can resolve my problems. Therefore, and I know this is not a preferred method, I've been using a `for` loop.

My Error is, I believe, occurring because the new vector has `NULL` values in it - although, I done the test manually (referring to the referenced cells and performing the `if` statement) and it should work.

The above said, it's not, and I'm stuck. Please find my code below;

**Data**

```
Prob <- 0.9
Bet <- 10
Trans <- Bet 
Spread <- (1-0.002)
StartingBalance <- 1000000
Days <- 3
> IndTest
           N225.Open    Close     High      Low    S.High      S.Low       S.OC
2007-01-04  17322.50 17353.67 17379.46 17315.76  56.96094   6.740234   31.16992
2007-01-05  17315.54 17091.59 17327.13 17011.10  11.59180 304.439453 -223.94922
2007-01-09  17018.89 17237.77 17261.03 16983.97 242.13867  34.919922  218.87891
2007-01-10  17192.42 16942.40 17199.42 16847.57   7.00000 344.849610 -250.01953
2007-01-11  16958.57 16838.17 17057.45 16758.46  98.87891 200.109374 -120.40039
2007-01-12  16979.73 17057.01 17160.77 16941.39 181.03906  38.339844   77.27930
2007-01-15  17160.25 17209.92 17273.58 17144.44 113.33008  15.810547   49.66992
2007-01-16  17190.90 17202.46 17287.96 17175.85  97.06055  15.050782   11.56055
2007-01-17  17153.25 17261.35 17335.03 17002.67 181.77930 150.580078  108.09961
2007-01-18  17248.14 17370.93 17408.62 17220.42 160.47852  27.720703  122.78906
           D.Pos D.Neg   H.S.Avg   L.S.Avg P.D.Up P.D.Dn
2007-01-04     1     0   0.00000   0.00000      0      0
2007-01-05     1     0   0.00000   0.00000      0      0
2007-01-09     1     0 103.56380 115.36654      1      0
2007-01-10     1     0  86.91016 228.06966      1      0
2007-01-11     1     0 116.00586 193.29297      1      0
2007-01-12     1     0  95.63932 194.43294      1      0
2007-01-15     1     0 131.08268  84.75325      1      0
2007-01-16     1     0 130.47656  23.06706      1      0
2007-01-17     1     0 130.72331  60.48047      1      0
2007-01-18     1     0 146.43945  64.45052      1      0
```

**Code**

```
IndTest <-Ind[1:10,]    
IndTest[is.na(IndTest)] <- 0
IndTest[is.null(IndTest)] <- 0
IndTest$P.Bal <- rep(0,nrow(IndTest))

for (i in 2:(nrow(IndTest)-2)){
   if (IndTest[i+2,5]> IndTest[i+1,10] & IndTest[i+1,12] > Prob){
   Ind$P.Bal[i+3] = Bet*IndTest[i+1,10]*Spread-Trans
   } else {
   Ind$P.Bal[i+2] = Bet*IndTest[i+2,7]*Spread-Trans
   }
}
```

**Breaking Down Error**

I've also tried to deconstruct the code and I'm even getting an error on;

**Basic if**

```
X <- if(IndTest[4,5] > IndTest[3,10]) {1}
```

**Basic if - Error**

```
Error in if (IndTest[4, 5] > IndTest[3, 10]) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Here is a `dput()`, as requested by @Coatless out put as requested earlier. It seems that this may be due to the POSIXT index?

```
structure(c(17322.5, 17315.539062, 17018.890625, 17192.419922, 
16958.570312, 16979.730469, 17160.25, 17190.900391, 17153.25, 
17248.140625, 17353.669922, 17091.589844, 17237.769531, 16942.400391, 
16838.169922, 17057.009766, 17209.919922, 17202.460938, 17261.349609, 
17370.929688, 17379.460938, 17327.130859, 17261.029297, 17199.419922, 
17057.449219, 17160.769531, 17273.580078, 17287.960938, 17335.029297, 
17408.619141, 17315.759766, 17011.099609, 16983.970703, 16847.570312, 
16758.460938, 16941.390625, 17144.439453, 17175.849609, 17002.669922, 
17220.419922, 56.9609380000002, 11.591797000001, 242.138672000001, 
7, 98.8789069999984, 181.039062000003, 113.330077999999, 97.060547000001, 
181.779297000001, 160.478515999999, 6.74023400000078, 304.439452999999, 
34.919922000001, 344.849610000001, 200.109374, 38.3398439999983, 
15.810547000001, 15.0507819999984, 150.580077999999, 27.720702999999, 
31.169922000001, -223.949218000002, 218.878906000002, -250.019531000002, 
-120.400389999999, 77.279297000001, 49.669922000001, 11.560547000001, 
108.099609000001, 122.789063, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103.563802333334, 86.910156333334, 
116.005859666666, 95.6393230000006, 131.082682333334, 130.476562333334, 
130.723307333334, 146.439453333334, 0, 0, 115.366536333334, 228.069661666667, 
193.292968666667, 194.432942666666, 84.7532549999996, 23.0670576666659, 
60.4804689999995, 64.4505209999988, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), .Dim = c(10L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("N225.Open", 
"Close", "High", "Low", "S.High", "S.Low", "S.OC", "D.Pos", "D.Neg", 
"H.S.Avg", "L.S.Avg", "P.D.Up", "P.D.Dn", "P.Bal")), index = structure(c(1167868800, 
1167955200, 1168300800, 1168387200, 1168473600, 1168560000, 1168819200, 
1168905600, 1168992000, 1169078400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1457986774.61692, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Comment: Use `dput()` to provide a reproducible `data.frame`.

Comment: figure out where you're doing this `if (NULL > 1) 1`

Comment: @effel Prob <- 0.9

Comment: @rawr this statement displays that I'm still getting an error when there is no `null` value in the data, ref: `if(IndTest[4,5] > IndTest[3,10]`

Comment: what is bet, what is speed, what is trans, come on we are trying to help you but this is wasting time, did you read the thing about minimal complete reproducible examples? and for loops dont have a return value, so `Ind$P.Bal <-for ` is also wrong

Comment: @rawr my apologies, I didn't realize the variables I've used hadn't been defined (I had thought I had included them). Please see the question adjusted above to include these.
I didn't, where could I find it and would you recommend it for my question?
I didn't realize, would you have any other suggestions? I have tried `ifelse` however I couldn't figure out defining cell input. 
Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Coatless I put the `dput()` example above. Do you think this is an indexing problem and something to do with POSIXT; you can see the `.Dimnames = list(NULL, c( ....` is this where the error is occuring?

Comment: `IndTest[i + 2, 5] > IndTest[i + 1, 10]` is where the error is being triggered. 

Seems as if it is a subsetting issue with `xts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue relates to a conditional fault after subsetting from the `xts` object.  To get around this, cast the values subset as `numeric` via `as.numeric`. Furthermore, you also will go out of bounds if `(nrow(IndTest)-2)` since `i+3` on `i=8` gives `index = 11`. Thus, I also changed it to: `(nrow(IndTest)-3)`

```
library("xts")
Prob <- 0.9
Bet <- 10
Trans <- Bet 
Spread <- (1-0.002)
StartingBalance <- 1000000
Days <- 3

IndTest = structure(c(17322.5, 17315.539062, 17018.890625, 17192.419922, 
            16958.570312, 16979.730469, 17160.25, 17190.900391, 17153.25, 
            17248.140625, 17353.669922, 17091.589844, 17237.769531, 16942.400391, 
            16838.169922, 17057.009766, 17209.919922, 17202.460938, 17261.349609, 
            17370.929688, 17379.460938, 17327.130859, 17261.029297, 17199.419922, 
            17057.449219, 17160.769531, 17273.580078, 17287.960938, 17335.029297, 
            17408.619141, 17315.759766, 17011.099609, 16983.970703, 16847.570312, 
            16758.460938, 16941.390625, 17144.439453, 17175.849609, 17002.669922, 
            17220.419922, 56.9609380000002, 11.591797000001, 242.138672000001, 
            7, 98.8789069999984, 181.039062000003, 113.330077999999, 97.060547000001, 
            181.779297000001, 160.478515999999, 6.74023400000078, 304.439452999999, 
            34.919922000001, 344.849610000001, 200.109374, 38.3398439999983, 
            15.810547000001, 15.0507819999984, 150.580077999999, 27.720702999999, 
            31.169922000001, -223.949218000002, 218.878906000002, -250.019531000002, 
            -120.400389999999, 77.279297000001, 49.669922000001, 11.560547000001, 
            108.099609000001, 122.789063, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103.563802333334, 86.910156333334, 
            116.005859666666, 95.6393230000006, 131.082682333334, 130.476562333334, 
            130.723307333334, 146.439453333334, 0, 0, 115.366536333334, 228.069661666667, 
            193.292968666667, 194.432942666666, 84.7532549999996, 23.0670576666659, 
            60.4804689999995, 64.4505209999988, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), .Dim = c(10L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("N225.Open", 
                                                "Close", "High", "Low", "S.High", "S.Low", "S.OC", "D.Pos", "D.Neg", 
                                                "H.S.Avg", "L.S.Avg", "P.D.Up", "P.D.Dn", "P.Bal")), index = structure(c(1167868800, 
                                                                                                                         1167955200, 1168300800, 1168387200, 1168473600, 1168560000, 1168819200, 
                                                                                                                         1168905600, 1168992000, 1169078400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1457986774.61692, class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))

Ind = IndTest

for (i in 2:(nrow(IndTest)-3)){
  a = as.numeric(IndTest[i+2,5])
  b = as.numeric(IndTest[i+1,10])
  c = as.numeric(IndTest[i+1,12])
  if (a > b & c > Prob){
    Ind$P.Bal[i+3] = Bet*IndTest[i+1,10]*Spread-Trans
  }else{
    Ind$P.Bal[i+2] = Bet*IndTest[i+2,7]*Spread-Trans
  }

}
```